# OpenType fonts and Microsoft PowerPoint

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, opentype

I'm trying to use an OpenType font (Quicksand) in PowerPoint and I've come across a few issues where:

- Not all font weights can be used
- Only some font weights can be used
- My desktop allows all font weights to be used, but my laptop will only allow one

So on my desktop, I can select Quicksand Regular, Quicksand Bold, etc. But on my laptop it only appears to as Quicksand despite installing the exact same fonts from the same .zip file source.

It's a massive problem when I'm working on the same document but on different PCs. I've tried looking for an answer but it's been extremely difficult to find a definitive solution.

FYI I tried on Office 365 and Office 2010; same results :(

Comment: What's different about the laptop vs the desktop?  Windows version, Office version/edition, updates to both/either?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg The two are identical, however I literally just found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution to this issue. After looking at the font files very carefully on both my desktop and laptop, it seems that there was a discrepancy in the **font files themselves**.

On my desktop, Every variation / weight of Quicksand had a **distinct font name** as follows:

```
Quicksand Bold
Quicksand Book
Quicksand Light
```

However on my laptop, every variation / weight of Quicksand had **the same non-distinct font name** like this:

```
Quicksand Bold
Quicksand Book
Quicksand Light
ALL THE ABOVE WERE NAMED AS Quicksand, REGARDLESS OF THE ACTUAL FONT NAME / WEIGHT
```

So in the end, it was not an issue with OpenType vs. TrueType or PowerPoint; but rather the fact that each font on my desktop was uniquely named while the ones on my laptop were *not*.

I only discovered the issue when I **opened and checked** each font file one by one and noticed how the fonts on my desktop were uniquely named (i.e. Quicksand Bold for the Bold weight), but not on my laptop (i.e. Quicksand for the Bold weight, when it *should* be Quicksand Bold).